# Can I string-build a Slick plain SQL query?

Tags: scala, slick, slick-3.0

I'm using Slick to assemble a plain SQL query.

I'd like to have *part of the query* constructed differently at runtime, depending on local variables.

This implies I need to concatenate multiple partial `SqlAction`s (I think?).

I understand an alternative approach is to use `#${plainSqlString}` but this would require me to manually convert my parameters to literals (e.g. `$delta` to `#$delta` below). However, for `String` parameters this would require manual SQL sanitization... which I want to avoid!

```
val delta      = 42

val applyDelta =
  if (limitNegatives)
    "GREATEST(0, col_1 + $delta)"
  else
    "col_1 + $delta"

val statement =
  sqlu"""
        UPDATE table_foo
        SET    col_1=#${applyDelta}
      """
```

Any ideas how to string-build a `SqlAction` with parameters (`$delta`) in each `SqlAction`?

Answer (score 0):

```
val delta      = 42

val applyDelta =
  if (limitNegatives)
    sqlu"UPDATE table_foo set col1 = GREATEST(0, col_1 + ${delta})"
  else
    sqlu"UPDATE table_foo set col1 = col_1 + ${delta}"
```

the value of applydelta is a SqlAction which can be executed

Comment: Interesting approach. Now imagine a very large query (20 lines) where only a small part changes (1 line), but changes in 4 different ways... your solution suggests you'd repeat the queries 4 times (so 80 lines total). Can you find a way, closer to the original question, which requires only 20+4 lines of SQL?

Comment: For the case you describe above. Don't use slick. Slick is good for typed queries with some parameters. But if you entire structure of the query (like table names or columsn) are dynamic then slick is not a good choice.